RGB to HSV representation
When altering RGB image representation to HSV in Matlab (rgb2hsv) should the human eye notice the difference? because the result image differs vastly.

There should be no difference since this is a lossless invertible transformation. How do you look at the HSV image? As far as I know, Matlab has no native function that can display HSV images. Whatever program you use to display  the picture needs to know  (and support) HSV data format. image() doesn't

I've used the imshow() function to present the image.
Thanks for dragging my attention to the Image() function it also caused an inconvenient.

So you convert RGB to HSV, then display the new data as is it were RGB. Of course that doesn’t work. You’d need to convert the HSV back to RGB before displaying with imshow or image.
